# How sitemesh decorator works without pattern?

Tags: java, web-applications, sitemesh

I have below configuration under my decorator.xml.

```
<decorators defaultdir="/includes">
    <decorator name="pageOne" page="page_one.jsp"/>
    <decorator name="pageTwo" page="page_two.jsp"/>
    <decorator name="pageThree" page="page_three.jsp"/>
    ...
</decorators>
```

I am not getting for which urls, these decorators will come into picture as pattern is not defined here something like below

```
<decorator name="pageOne" page="page_one.jsp">
        <pattern>/data/*</pattern>
</decorator>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Sitemesh uses the following logic:

1. Does the page request a decorator using a meta decorator tag?
2. Is the page a frame set? If so, don't apply decorator
3. From above, does the page has a "pageOne=true" or pageTwo and Three? If so then use that jsp page

So in this case you just provide parameters to apply the rule.